# Subsequent Python Script Processing Doesn't Adjust Zoom to Selected Features

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.5

I have a script that I load into ArcMap 10.5's Python window and I run it and it works fine. If I go back to the script and change a data value for the a selection to look for, and then load it again, it will run, but won't zoom to my desired location. I want to be able to load the code to search for 'NY' and then load the code again after changing 'NY' to 'OH'. When it tries to zoom to Ohio, it zooms to the layer extent, not the state extent like it does the first time.

```
import arcpy

#DEFINE VARIABLES
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer("NP_Allowances")
lyr2 = arcpy.mapping.Layer("National_NPs")

#CREATE SELECTION LAYER AND WHERE CLAUSE
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(lyr,"NEW_SELECTION"," STATE_ABBR = 'OH' ")

#ZOOM TO STATE SELECTION THEN CLEAR SELECTION
df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(lyr, "CLEAR_SELECTION")

lyr.definitionQuery = "STATE_ABBR = 'OH'"
lyr2.definitionQuery = "VAR32 = 'OH'"

#UPDATE MAP ELEMENTS
for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT"):
    if elm.name == "Title":
        elm.text = elm.text.replace("Map of NPs", "Practice Locations of NY Nurse Practitioners")

#CLEAR DEFINITION QUERIES AND UPDATE MAP VIEW
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

#DELETE LOCAL VARIABLES
del mxd, df, lyr, lyr2
```

Comment: if you comment out where you reset the selection, does the map show the selection correctly?

Comment: No, commenting it out on the second run returns same result. Besides, I need it to reset the selection so that the next line can kick off the zoom to selection command.

If I do that for the first run, it zooms out to the feature extent which is the same result as the subsequent results. So, when I load it the second time, it's skipping over this line when I declare a new state:

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(lyr,"NEW_SELECTION"," STATE_ABBR = 'OH' ")

Comment: Are NP_Allowances and National_NPs existing layer files, or are they layers in your MXD?

Comment: Both are layer in the MXD, but only NP_Allowances is a separate layer file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why it works once, but I think the problem has something to do with that `df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()` zooms to features that are selected *inside the dataframe*.

But if `NP_Allowances` is also a feature class or layer file in your current workspace, `lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer("NP_Allowances")` makes a new layer object *in memory*.

So you can make a selection against that layer object, but the since it's not the layer in the dataframe its selection is unknown to the dataframe.

One solution might be to get the extent of the selection, then set the dataframe's view to that extent.

```
#ZOOM TO STATE SELECTION THEN CLEAR SELECTION
#df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
df.extent = lyr.getSelectedExtent()
```

The other solution would be to get direct references to the layers in the MXD so that you're selecting against a layer in the dataframe:

```
for layer in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    if layer.name == "NP_Allowances":
        lyr = layer
    if layer.name == "National_NPs":
        lyr2 = layer
```

Comment: The second solution worked, but not the first one. the 'df.extent = lyr.getSelectedExtent()' line only selected the new state, but kept the extent on the previous selection. Thank you for your input!

Comment: Glad to hear one of them worked, could you mark this as solved?

Comment: Where do you solve the ticket?

Comment: click the green checkmark to the left of the post